# Discord.js command hendler

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

Здраствуйте, появилась небольшая проблема, начинал создавать бота я много "заимствовал" чужой код, а теперь страдаю, так как не могу внести корректировки.
К сути проблемы: у меня есть "менеджер команд" вот так он выглядит:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()
const db = require('quick.db');
const { readdirSync } = require('fs');
const { join } = require('path');
const prefix = (`!`);
const logs = require('discord-logs');

logs(client);

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const commandFiles = readdirSync(join(__dirname, "commands")).filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
  const command = require(join(__dirname, "commands", `${file}`));
  client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.on("message", async message => {

  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (message.channel.type === 'dm') return;
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return db.add(`${message.author.id}.msg`, 1);
  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix)) {
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);

    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (!client.commands.has(command)) return;


    try {
      client.commands.get(command).run(client, message, args);

    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
  
})
```

а вот так выглядит пример команды:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
    name: "ping",
    description: "test command",

    async run (client, message, args) {
        message.channel.bulkDelete(1, true);


        const ping = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setDescription(`\`${client.ws.ping}\`ms`);


        message.channel.send(ping);
    }
}
```

И мне бы хотелось добавить возможность "вариативности" написания этой команды, не добавляя несколько файлов (Пример: !ping выполняет команду и !serverping выполняет ее же)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [алиасы](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/adding-features.html#command-aliases) команд:

```
module.exports = {
    name: "ping",
    aliases: ['serverping', 'anotherping'],
    description: "test command",
```